# What is difference between self signed and certificate generated by certification authority

Tags: .net, wcf, security, certificate, ssl-certificate

I want to know the difference between self signed and certificate generated by certification authority.

I can easily create a self signed certificate for domain xyz.com then what is the difference between this certificate and the one generated by CA?

**Scenario**

Suppose a site **xyz.com** is secured with a certificate issued to **xyz.com** and it can be accessed by the clients who have the certificate issued by the site.

I can also create a self signed for **xyz.com** then how will my server take care of this fake certificate?

Comment: To the closers... I would almost agree that this should be on serverfault.com, but at the same time this is information that developers using PKI should know.

Comment: Who's identity are you interested in? Are you trying to ascertain that the client is who it claims to be, or that the server is who it claims to be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the CA's certificate is already installed in your browser, then when your browser encounters a certificate that claims to be signed by a certain CA it can verify that it was indeed signed by that CA. The CA itself usually verifies your identity in some way or other before signing your certificate.

Your self-signed certificate is just signed by your own CA. No one verified that the certificate actually belongs to the person it claims to belong. You *can* install your own CA's root certificate into your browser. That way you won't get those annoying warning messages about the certificate. Other users usually won't have your own CA's root certificate installed and will still get the warning.

Comment: So suppose there is a secure service at xyz.com. If I create a self signed dummy certificate issued to xyz.com . In this situation, can I expect that the server on which the xyz.com is hosted, will detect my certificate as invalid one?

Comment: @Ram - The server doesn't care about the certificate; the client is the one who would care.

Comment: Here is the Wiki page with more details about CAs and PKI http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_infrastructure

Answer (score 4):

There's no difference between the certificates themselves. The important part is that the CA acts as a **trusted** third party. I.e. the client may not know who you are, but if they trust the CA, and the CA vouches for you, then they can trust you. It is not as much the certificate itself, but the chain of trust the CA provides.

Answer (score 2):

The CA also does some verification that you are who you say you are, so they add an extra level of confidence when using a site.  Self signed cert may not also get a full 'padlock' on a client's browser.

Answer (score 1):

And to complete the other answers the operating system comes preinstalled with some root certificates from Microsoft or other trusted authorities. if your certificate is signed by one of those then no warning will be shown. if a certificate is signed by a CA that the OS does not recognize then it will display a warning.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference between a self-signed certificate and one issued by a CA is the trust chain.  If you sign your own certificate then when you or others use it they will have to specifically trust the server you signed the certificate with.  The way to do this is to add the certificate to your list of "trusted CA roots" in your browser (i.e. Firefox, or Microsoft's CAPI store for MSIE or Chrome), or your `cacerts` file for Java applications.  Otherwise your self-signed certificate won't be trusted and you will get a "warning" or error message depending on how strict your security settings are in that environment (i.e. Java or your specific browser).

With a certificate that is signed by a CA you won't get that warning if either the CA that signed the certificate, or the CA's trusted Root (the one that signed that CA's certificate), is already in your relevant truststore (i.e. browser or `cacerts` file for Java).  Microsoft and Oracle (for Java) are constantly updating trusted CA's and managing CRLs (Certificate Revocation Lists), for CA's or authorities that have been compromised or revoked.

Usually one of these trusted CAs (like verisign, entrust, etc.) charge $$ for signing and issuing certificates and the longer the validity period the more they charge.

A self-signed one is free and may be issued for a long period of time (though not recommended).